# Getting value of URL-encoded request.GET variable in Django Template

Tags: django, django-templates

I am using Django 1.3 with Python 2.7.2 on Windows 7 x64.

I have a URL pattern like this:

```
url(r'^(?P<club_id>\d+)/$', 'view_club')
```

From the pattern I want to be able to use request.GET in my templates to be able to create URLs to my views based on this GET variable (club_id). I have read online that I would be able to do:

```
{{ request.GET.club_id }}
```

However, this is always showing up as blank. I cannot figure out the reason why. I have the request context processor in my list of default context processors.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

In your example, `club_id` is not a GET parameter, it is part of the path in the URL.  Your view function takes `club_id` as an argument, it should then put it in the context so the template can access it.

For example, your view function:

```
def view_club(request, club_id):
     return render(request, "template_name.html", { 'club_id': club_id })
```

then in your template:

```
{{ club_id }}
```

Comment: Sorry, I literally posted mine at the same time. If I would have saw your answer first I wouldn't have posted : p

Comment: Is it possible to set up the URL so that I would be able to access it like I want? I don't want to have to edit 24+ views to include this in the context dict. I already thought of a context processor, but I don't think it's possible.

Comment: @Craysiii: you don't need to mention GET parameters in your url patterns at all.  Change your code to use `?club_id=123`, then your original code should work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

IF you are passing an variable in the URL - in this case club_id - simply include it as an argument in your view function next to request:

```
def get_club(request,club_id):
     club = Club.object.get(pk=club_id)
     return render_to_response('club.html', {'club': club})
```

now in your template you can access {{club}} as the individually selected object and do things like {{club.name}}    This also works for variables with multiple objects which you would use a for loop to iterate through.